# Importing problem, how can i solve this syntax error?

Tags: python

I'm novice in python. I use anaconda Jupiter Notebook, i'm trying to use a module named weka, i installed it with pip. But now I find this error:

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2961, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 14, in 
>       from weka.classifiers import Classifier, Evaluation, PredictionOutput
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\weka\classifiers.py", line
>   2169
>       except Exception, e:
>                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Somebody can help me? guess is a stupid error, but i can't solve it..

Comment: You seems to use a Python 2 only library on Python 3.

Comment: How have you come to that conclusion @Klaus D.  I'm sorry but there is nowhere that say he is using Python 2.x, infact, I'm sure he is using Python 3.x because of the Anaconda version he is using.

To the OP:Have you ever used Pycharm? You should check it out.

Comment: `except Exception, e:` is Python 2 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to upgrade weka. In the current version of [`classifiers.py`](https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/blob/master/weka/classifiers.py), the `except ... as ...:` lines are Python3 compatible.

But it does appear that the fixes in the current codebase are [not on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/weka/#history) so you'll probably need to install from source. [See this guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs) for how you could do that. And perhaps post an issue about it on the GitHub repo.